# Konqueror on Windows XP : protocol not supported - man

Tags: windows, konqueror

I am new to KDE and work all the time in a Windows XP environment.

I installed KDE's Konqueror browser onto my laptop.

The only reason for that is to allow me to type:

```
man:ls
```

in the browser address bar and get the man page displayed into the browser rather than printed inside the terminal.

The problem is, I then get an error prompt saying:

```
protocol not supported man
```

I guess something is wrong in the configuration. How can I fix this problem? The problem is definitely not the Konqueror browser, but is between the keyboard and the screen.

Comment: Isn't it easier to Google for `man ls`